# WORDPRESS CDN - Cloudfront aws font awesome CORS

Tags: wordpress, cors

I've configured a w3 total cache plugin working on aws cloudfront.
The whole site is working.
The images is loading correctly but font awesome not.

How can I fix that?

This not working (but if I go directly to the link, it download the font file): https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff

This working: https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Immagine-2022-11-22-163209-1536x472.png

ERROR in console:

```
Access to font at 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/lib/font-awesome/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2' from origin 'https://xxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyyy.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I've tried to edit the .htaccess with no result:
FILE: /opt/bitnami/wordpress/.htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ".(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)">
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

[image]

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved temporarily using this configuration on Behaviours of my cloudfront setting:

[image]

With this settings the response contains:

> access-control-allow-origin: *